# Duplicate widgets and pages in apostrophe cms

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am building a site using apostrophe cms for users to create different layouts and receive feedback. Having said that, I was wondering if it's possible to duplicate widgets within pages as well as duplicate pages so that widgets can be reused within pages(layout templates) and pages to use the same layout with other languages.

Thanks!

Comment: D, are you referring to different spoken languages. E.g. you'd like the same pages and widgets in English, French, and Spanish?

Comment: I don't need to have the site in different languages as pages are used to create layouts for different content. Meaning that my users need to create a page that will be used to layout and check how information can be displayed in different languages. So, it will be much easier if they can duplicate a page and then change content to whatever language they need, rather than creating another page from the scratch, if only content will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is localization across multiple languages, then this is actually possible with the new Apostrophe 2.x version of the `apostrophe-workflow` module. It is still in beta but it is in a late stage of validation by an enterprise client and should be npm published quite soon. There is documentation covering how to use it now if you wish to be a beta tester:

https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe-workflow/tree/2.x

The new version of the workflow module integrates localization and approvals in a way that allows for exporting content between locales gracefully; it's very much what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Hi Boutell, Thank you for your answer. I realised copy page was part of the answer for this post. However, this option is made available for editor users even thought they are not allowed to actually copy/duplicate the page. It seems only users with admin permissions, and permissions to edit the home page (as parent for all pages) are able to copy any page. I was wondering if it is possible to change grant editor users with permissions on copy page funtionality.